# Thicker arrows in xymatrix

Tags: arrows

I would like to have thicker arrows when using the \xymatrix environment, so I searched and found the following resources:

1. [Larger arrows in xy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49527/larger-arrows-in-xy)  (unresolved at present)
2. The link in the second comment of the question presents a sort of hack by enlarging the entire diagram and calling \tiny on the text.

I tried to apply the approach in the manual on page 28 (screenshot below) but the arrows all end up with the same size when I compile it on my TeXShop on my Mac.

[image: What it should look like]

The file I used to generate the example is below:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}

\begin{document}

\xy/r8pc/:*++\txt\huge{C}="c"
,0*++\txt\huge{P}="p",
,"p",{\ar@*{[|(1)]}"p";"c"<20pt>}
,"p",{\ar@*{[|(4)]}"p";"c"<14pt>}
,"p",{\ar@*{[|(10)]}"p";"c"<4pt>}
,"p",{\ar@*{[|(20)]}"p";"c"<-16pt>}
\endxy

\end{document}
```

And I get the following warning message in LaTeX

[image: xy-pic-warning]

I also tried the solution suggested in a message board post which is to use

```
\usepackage[dvips,ps,all]{xypic}
```

instead but then the arrows disappear altogether with the warning: *Non-PDF special ignored!* repeated a bunch of times.

Comment: In order to use the dvips driver, you need to go the `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` way.